# Equivariance definition

Tags: neural-networks, invariance, graph-neural-network

*Equivariance* in deep learning, it is actually defined as a property of some function $f$ to permute the outputs according to permutation of inputs, i.e.

$$f(PAP^T) = Pf(A)P^T$$

for some permutation matrix $P \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$, and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. But I also find the following (guess equivalent) statement,

$$f(P^TAP) = P^Tf(A)P.$$

I know that applying $P$ on the left ($PA$) it will permute the rows of $A$ while permuting on the right ($AP$) we will permute the columns. Why should I use $P^T$? I don't fully understand the definition.

Comment: These definitions are clearly equivalent: merely replace "$P$" in the first definition by "$P^T$" and use the fact that $(P^T)^T=P.$

Comment: Also, why do we need transpose? Can't we just write $f(PAP) = Pf(A)P$ ?

Comment: The general definition of equivariance uses $P^{-1}$ rather than $P^T.$  However, because permutation matrices are orthogonal, necessarily $P^{-1}=P^T$ in that case.  Using just $P$ on both sides makes little sense unless $P=P^{-1}.$